# How to output element height in an alert box (height is stored in a variable)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why when I try to output element height (which is in stored variable) I get an alert box :

https://jsfiddle.net/2z7yLwhf/

I want to alert the number which is the height of div.item1...

jQuery:

```
function number() {
    var number = $('.item1').height($('.item2').outerHeight());
    alert(number);
}
number();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a parenthesis mismatch. It should be

```
var number = $('.item1').height($('.item2')).outerHeight();
```

since you want to get the height, and then extract outerHeight.

https://jsfiddle.net/2z7yLwhf/1/

EDIT: This is really a workaround -- I don't actually know why it works. Do it this way instead:

```
var number = $('.item1').outerHeight();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2z7yLwhf/2/

Comment: I literally included a link to a jsfiddle where I use exactly that code and it works.

Comment: It doesn't work; the `height(...)` call does nothing.

Comment: Looks like the correct height to me. Computed height of 18px. Alert outputs 18. https://streamable.com/q99sa

Answer (score 0):

`.height(...)` returns the the jQuery object (for chaining), not the height you passed it.

You need to store the number first.

Comment: var number2 = parseInt(number) ?

Comment: @Piotr: No; you need to get the number, store it, then pass it to both `height()` and `alert()`.